# how do i print out rpm sudo --version in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
if rpm -q sudo > /dev/null; then
        echo "sudo is installed and version is"
else
        echo "sudo is not installed"
fi
```

hi was wondering if it is possible to print out my sudo version after checking that it is installed. If there's a way, how can I do it

Comment: Add output of `sudo --version` to your question.

Comment: So remove `-q` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk what do i echo out if I want to see the version instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo --version` output must be parsed and the return status used to determine if it is installed.

First of all, you want the version output to be consistent, regardless of active system locale.

So you invoke it with `LANG=C sudo --version`.

This prints multiple lines and only the first line last element is the sudo version:

```
Sudo version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers file grammar version 48
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers audit plugin version 1.9.5p2
```

Using POSIX-shell grammer, lines and field parsing must be done with external tools. Here `awk` is capable of parsing it all at once:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Captures version string parsed with awk:
# so only last entry of first line is captured
if sudo_version=$(LANG=C sudo --version 2>/dev/null | awk 'NR==1{print $NF}')
  then printf 'sudo is installed and version is %s\n' "$sudo_version"
  else printf 'sudo is not installed\n' >&2
fi
```

If using Bash, capturing the first line into an array save from using external tools and pipe forking process:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Capture version string first line into a Bash array
if read -ra version_array < <(LANG=C sudo --version 2>/dev/null)
then
  # Version is the last element of array
  printf 'sudo is installed and version is %s\n' "${version_array[-1]}"
else
  printf 'sudo is not installed\n' >&2
fi
```